# how to create link back from contributor section of google plus for dynamic pages

Tags: google, google-plus, rich-snippets, author

I wanted to add author information for my programming articles. I have added Google plus profile link to my site and followed further instructions by Google.

In that Google had mentioned that from the article there should be a link to Google plus profile and a link back in Google plus contributor section to that articles. I have a section in my website which generates content from database. So when ever an article has been added from the admin site it appears in the front end, like a blog.

I was reading this blob http://www.buuteeq.com/blog/googles-authorship-markup-author-vs-publisher/ which insisted i create a link back.

In this case how do I add link back in Google plus contributor section? is just linking from my website to Google plus enough?

Answer (score 1):

> In this case how do i add link back in Google plus contributor
>   section? **is just linking from my website to Google plus enough**?

Absolutely! Simply link to their Google Plus account, ensure that you only ever have one link on a page at a time otherwise it doesn't work, you can read more by using the link below (No need to do option 1). If you don't want to use a link then you will need to confirm each publisher on your Google account.

> [Author information in search results](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986&expand=option2)
>
> Create a link to your Google+ profile from your webpage, like this:
>
> `<a href="[profile_url]?rel=author">Google</a>`
>
> Replace [profile_url] with the your Google+ profile URL, like this:
>
> `<a href="https://plus.google.com/109412257237874861202?
>
>   rel=author">Google</a>`
>
> Your link must contain the ?rel=author parameter. If it's missing,
>   Google won't be able to associate your content with your Google+
>   profile. Add a reciprocal link back from your profile to the site(s)
>   you just updated.
>
> Edit the Contributor To section.
>   In the dialog that appears, click Add custom link, and then enter the website URL.
>   If you want, click the drop-down list to specify who can see the link.
>   Click Save.
>
> To see what author data Google can extract from your page, use the structured data testing tool.

Comment: An alternative markup is `<a href="[profile_url]" rel="author">Some text here</a>`

Comment: how updated is this?

Comment: Many ways, depends on what content management system you use, or static files.

Comment: I mean to say, from 2013 is this tag still valid and works?

Comment: @azerafati Google dropped support to Authorship in SERPs since 2014. As per my research you can drop "rel=author" since google said it is now ignored. But you shall use "rel=me" to link to your different profiles (twitter, facebook, g+, etc) and use "rel=publisher" to link your G+ business page.

Comment: And you want to embedded schema.org markup as well (including author and publisher property when applicable)